# Why is =sys-libs/glibc-2.16's --enable-kernel is ignored on Gentoo Linux?

Tags: compiling, gentoo, glibc

I'm trying to build eglibc support for old kernels, 2.6.9 in this case.

So I set `NPTL_KERNEL_VER` in make.conf, and during configuration phrase I can see the `--enable-kernel=2.6.9` parameter

But this seems to be reverted:

```
checking installed Linux kernel header files... 2.6.19 or later
configure: WARNING: minimum kernel version reset to 2.6.16
```

Any ideas? (I'm building `=sys-libs/glibc-2.16` for `i686-pc-linux-gnu`.)

Comment: What target are you building for, and what version of eglibc is this?

Comment: @Mat 2.16 and 2.17, none of them works

Comment: @Mat target is i686-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: Can you file a bug at https://bugs.gentoo.org, such that the base system maintainers can look into this for you? Can you also please attach the complete build.log and config.log to that bug report, as well as comment with the output of emerge --info. This information will greatly help us debugging this for you. Their locations are given at the end of the emerge output. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your message is unrelated to your problem, and is related to the build requirements of glibc (not the compiled interface), but the second line is your problem.

At first glance, you are using the wrong variable to set your minimum kernel version. Try setting `NPTL_KERN_VER` in make.conf. The ebuild uses this variable name and sets the default to 2.6.16.  From `/usr/portage/sys-libs/glibc/glibc-2.16.0.ebuild`:

```
NPTL_KERN_VER=${NPTL_KERN_VER:-"2.6.16"}       # min kernel version nptl requires
```

This is also the variable that gets passed to `configure` in the file `/usr/portage/sys-libs/glibc/files/eblits/src_compile.eblit`:

```
myconf+=( --enable-kernel=${NPTL_KERN_VER} )
```

Note that this configure variable can also be set to from the variable `LT_KER_VER` if `linuxthreads` is the threading option vs `nptl`.

You report however that you are seeing `--enable-kenrel=2.6.9` which implies that you are setting the variable correctly, and perhaps misnaming it in your post.

This leads us to the configure scripts and the file `glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/configure.in` where the test is made for the minimum kernel version.  The test is:

```
if test -n "$minimum_kernel"; then
   changequote(,)
   user_version=$((`echo "$minimum_kernel.0.0.0" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1 \* 65536 + \2 \    * 256 + \3/'`))
   arch_version=$((`echo "$arch_minimum_kernel.0.0.0" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1 \* 65536 +     \2 \* 256 + \3/'`))
   changequote([,])
   if test $user_version -lt $arch_version; then
     AC_MSG_WARN([minimum kernel version reset to $arch_minimum_kernel])
     minimum_kernel=$arch_minimum_kernel
   fi
 else
   minimum_kernel=$arch_minimum_kernel
 fi
```

where `$minimum_kernel` is the value provided to `configure` e.g. `2.6.9` and `$arch_minimum_kernel` is `2.4.0` set a few lines above this snippet.  What is confusing now is that when evaluated:

```
user_version=132617 (from 2.6.9)
arch_version=132096 (from 2.4.0)
test 132617 -lt 132096 (FALSE)
```

which should result in `minimum_kernel` being unchanged.  Instead what is happening is that you are triggering the warning and the version is being reset to `$arch_minimum_kernel`, which is reportedly 2.6.16 in your case.  I cannot find a reference to `$arch_minimum_kernel` being set to this value elsewhere in the glibc code or the gentoo patchset, so I am not sure quite what is going on in your case.

When I run `configure` manually with the command line:

```
../glibc/configure --enable-kernel=2.6.9 --prefix=/usr
```

it runs successfully with this in the output:

```
checking for kernel header at least 2.6.9... ok
```

It seems that something is different for you and I'm looking to see if I can find a patch that might be applying a different `arch_minimum_kernel` for you or perhaps in a file that I've overlooked.

#### UPDATE

I have located a possible source of 2.6.16 being your minimum version.  That kernel version is set to `arch_minimum_kernel` for the `arm` port in the file `glibc-ports-2.16.0/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/configure.in`.  Please verify that you have not messed up your ARCH target and are in fact compiling for i686, as you should not be seeing that version.  This is the only reference to that kernel version (2.6.16) I can find in the files downloaded by gentoo (glibc, glibc-ports and gentoo patches).